# PInvoke and EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I can't understand what is wrong with a pinvoke below which results into an EntryPointNotFoundException:

A function in C with a structure declaration:

```
    extern "C"__declspec (dllimport) __stdcall
    LONG NET_DVR_Login_V30 (char *sDVRIP,  WORD wDVRPort,  char *sUserName,
                        char *sPassword,  LPNET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 lpDeviceInfo);

    typedef struct
    {
        BYTE sSerialNumber[48]; 
        BYTE byAlarmInPortNum;
        BYTE byAlarmOutPortNum;
        BYTE byDiskNum;
        BYTE byDVRType;
        BYTE byChanNum;
        BYTE byStartChan;
        BYTE byAudioChanNum;
        BYTE byIPChanNum;
        BYTE byZeroChanNum;
        BYTE byMainProto;
        BYTE bySubProto;
        BYTE bySupport;
        BYTE byRes1[20];
    }NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30,  *LPNET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30;
```

The import in C#, the structure declaration and the pinvoke:

```
    [DllImport("SDK.dll", SetLastError = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static int NET_DVR_Login_V30(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sDVRIP,
            ushort wDVRPort,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sUserName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string sPassword,
            ref NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 lpDeviceInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 48)]
            public string sSerialNumber;
            public byte byAlarmOutPortNum;
            public byte byDiskNum;
            public byte byDVRType;
            public byte byChanNum;
            public byte byStartChan;
            public byte byAudioChanNum;
            public byte byIPChanNum;
            public byte byZeroChanNum;
            public byte byMainProto;
            public byte bySubProto;
            public byte bySupport;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
            public string byRes1;
        }

           NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 deviceInfo = new NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30();
           int result = Functions.NET_DVR_Login_V30(ip, port, user,
                                                 password, ref deviceInfo);
```

I inspected the function name via dumpbin and it is not mangled. So I wonder why an EntryPointNotFoundException occurs, if anything were wrong with the parameters for example, a PInvokeStackImbalance error would occur, let's say.
Any ideas what could be wrong with this pinvoke?

Comment: That code cannot compile, the function doesn't have a return type.  Furthermore, there's no space before __declspec and it should be declared *dllexport*.  Copy and paste the declaration *exactly* as it appears in your source code, accuracy is essential.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the return type - LONG - while expanding defines and concatenating the function declaration. The rest is okay, not declared variables in the pinvoke snippet have the types as the DllImport declaration defines.

Comment: As to _extern "C"__declspec (dllimport)_, it is this way in the header file that is used by other libraries for the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called Dependency Walker (`depends.exe`) that will help debug this issue by displaying the import/export table of your SDK.DLL - I'd take a look at that. One other thing that *might* (this seems suspect to me) be happening is, that since you're using char*, .NET is adding an "A" on the end of your function name. That could be balderdash though.

Comment: I tried tools such as Dependency Walker and DumpBin. They all say the function name is the same as in the DllImport - _NET_DVR_Login_V30_. Also I tried to set ExactSpelling to true, but in vain. Also I tried to call another function from this library without any parameters - _NET_DVR_GetLastError ()_ - and it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is a name mismatch. You therefore need to make sure that both sides of the interface use the same name:

- When exporting the function from the DLL as stdcall it will be decorated. You can avoid this decoration by using a .def file.
- When importing using P/Invoke you need to suppress the addition of a `W` or `A` suffix. Do so by setting the [`ExactSpelling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.exactspelling%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) field of the `DllImportAttribute` to `true`.

Comment: I think, as well, that this exception occurs when there is a name mismatch. But strangely enough the names fully coincide, I checked the name via DumpBin - it is _NET_DVR_Login_V30_ in the library, also I tried to set ExactSpelling to _true_ in the DllImport.