# EntryPointNotFoundException when binding C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, dllimport, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I try to bind a simple c++ dll shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx in my c# console app, but I get a EntryPointNotFoundException for Add within dll at runtime. My test class is

```
namespace BindingCppDllExample
{
    public class BindingDllClass
    {
        [DllImport("MathFuncsDll.dll")]
        public static extern double Add(double a, double b);
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a = 2.3;
            double b = 3.8;
            double c = BindingDllClass.Add(a, b);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, c));
        }
    }
}
```

What is not correct?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877349/pinvoke-and-entrypointnotfoundexception

Comment: I am going to guess that your CallingConvention does not match.  I also assume that the MathFuncsDll.dll doesn't declare a method named `Add` as exportable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try declaring the functions outside of a class and also exporting them with `extern "C"`:

Header:

```
// MathFuncsDll.h
namespace MathFuncs
{
    // Returns a + b
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);

    // Returns a - b
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);

    // Returns a * b
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);

    // Returns a / b
    // Throws DivideByZeroException if b is 0
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
}
```

Implementation:

```
// MyMathFuncs.cpp
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
        }

        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
namespace BindingCppDllExample
{
    public class BindingDllClass
    {
        [DllImport("MathFuncsDll.dll")]
        public static extern double Add(double a, double b);
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a = 2.3;
            double b = 3.8;
            double c = BindingDllClass.Add(a, b);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, c));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I have large classes I would have to wrap all methods I want to use, isn't it?

Comment: You could organize them in namespaces. I don't think that you could call C++ class methods using P/Invoke because P/Invoke was created to call any unmanaged code (including plain C in which the notion of a class doesn't exist). So you could still use classes in your unmanaged code but only expose the functions you need to be called from the managed code.

Answer (score 7):

In cases such as this, you can download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), load your DLL into it and look at the Export Functions list. You can also use [DumpBin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) for this.

By default, function exported from a C++ or C DLL are using [Name Decoration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (also called [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).

As said on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ax8kbk1.aspx):

> A decorated name for a C++ function contains the following
>   information:
>
> - The function name.
> - The class that the function is a member of, if it is a member function. This may include the class that encloses the function's class, and so on.
> - The namespace the function belongs to (if it is part of a namespace).
> - The types of the function's parameters.
> - The calling convention.
> - The return type of the function.

So decorated name for your `Add` function, for example, will look like `Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z`.

But it is possible to force the C++ compiler to expose undecorated names for C++ functions by enclosing the function, and any function prototypes, within an `extern "C" {…}` block, as Darin Dimitrov suggested.

Although if you're going to use a third-party DLL (so you can't modify it) or you just don't want to expose decorated names for some reason, you can specify the function's name explicitly:

```
[DllImport("MathFuncsDll.dll", EntryPoint = "Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")]
public static extern double Add(double a, double b);
```

Comment: I used dumpbin, but did not know what to do with it. Thanks for good advice with EntryPoint